# Do memory channels use separate pins for data bus in Intel i7-4600U?

Tags: memory, cpu

[i7-4600U datasheet](http://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/datasheets/4th-gen-core-family-desktop-vol-1-datasheet.pdf) says that SA_DQ[63:0] is used for memory channel A. And SB_DQ[63:0] is used for memory channel B. So my understanding is that memory channel A and memory channel B use different processor pins for each own's data bus.

Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The presence of the of *SA_DQ[63:0]* and *SB_DQ[63:0]* pretty much says it all.
The are two physical channels.

---

If you still need a secondary "prof", you can also check the math of this statement in the datasheet

> Theoretical maximum memory bandwidth of:
>         — 21.3 GB/s in dual-channel mode assuming 1333 MT/s
>         — 25.6 GB/s in dual-channel mode assuming 1600 MT/s

With 1333MT/s<sup>1</sup> and 8 Bytes per transfer we got 1333 * 8 = 10.664 GB/s.
In order to have a 21.3 GB/s peak, two channels must be used *simultaneously*, thus they must have separate pins.

---

<sup>1</sup> [Note that Mega-transfers per second is given by the internally multiplied bus clock (multiplier is fixed to four) times two, due to the double data rate. So 1333MT/s uses a 1333/2 = 666.67 MHz internal clock that corresponds to a 666.67/4 = 133.37 MHz bus clock.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DDR3_SDRAM#JEDEC_standard_modules)